# Remove anything not in an array

Tags: php, regex

I've been playing around with the `preg_` functions for a while now with no luck. I tried removing segments of a string, I tried taking them out and putting them back together etc., without luck.

I have an array of allowed characters or segments, and I simply want to remove anything from a string that isn't in this array. How can I do this without ruining the structure of the string?

This is what I would expect it to do:

```
$allowed = array('<', '>', 'p', 'sc');
echo clean('<script>'); // <scp>
```

**Bonus question:** Should I use `mb_ereg_match` to ensure UTF-8 works aswell?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing everything but a set of characters is easily done with an expressen such as `[^a-c]`, which matches everything but the lower-case characters `a, b, c`. For character sequences (like your `sc`) this will of course not work.

But if you know which characters you want to keep, you could turn the game around. Extract what you want to keep, ignore the rest:

```
<?php
$text = 'hello <script> |world # / foo';

$allowed = array('<', '>', 'p', 'sc', '|', '#');
array_walk($allowed, function(&$value){
    $value = preg_quote($value, '#');
});
$pattern = '#' . join('|', $allowed) . '#iu';

$text = preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
$text = join('', $matches[0]);
echo $text, "\n";
```

> Bonus question: Should I use mb_ereg_match to ensure UTF-8 works aswell?

PCRE can do UTF-8 with the `/u` flag. mb_ereg_* are slower than PCRE and should only be used when dealing with Charset other than UTF-8 ISO-8859-1

---

```
array_walk($allowed, function(&$value){
    $value = preg_quote($value, '#');
});
```

may just as well be

```
foreach ($allowed as &$value) {
    $value = preg_quote($value, '#');
};
```

the latter is probably a teeny bit faster…

Comment: Great answer! This was exactly what I was looking for even though I had to add a few minor modifications to make square brackets work. I also read the part about your answer to the bonus question just a few weeks ago, it's a wonder how quickly one can forget ;)

Comment: You can’t use `preg_quote` directly in `array_walk($allowed, 'preg_quote')` as `array_walk` passes the value as first and the key as second parameter but `preg_quote` expects the second to be the delimiter.